# Pass clicked cell value to excel function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking for a way to pass the current value of a cell at the time that the cell is clicked to a function as as an argument of that function. Or if there is anyway to access the cell value from the called function.

I tried using ActiveCell.value, but it gives wrong information if the cell with the focus is not the cell being clicked.

Currently I have a series of checkboxes to which I have assigned a single common macro. When any of the checkboxes is clicked the macro will of course run and I would like to use in the macro the value of the checkbox that has been clicked. I'm trying to avoid creating a separate macro for every checkbox.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178738/onclick-in-excel-vba

Comment: Are you looking to check when a checkbox is clicked or when a cell is clicked?

Comment: When any one of several checkboxes is clicked, a single function is called and I wanted that function to have available either the address of the cell linked to that clicked checkbox, or the linked cells value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want:

```
activesheet.checkboxes(application.caller).value
```

Comment: Thanks Josie. That's exactly what I need, I see I can also get the row number where the checkbox is located by using activesheet.checkboxes(application.caller).TopLeftCell.Row